# How to ignore max body width to allow certain divs to expand outside that width?

Tags: html, css

There are similar question to my answer but I couldn't find any that works for my problem, basically I set the body width to 960px as its the standards must of the time, however there are feel things that I want to be ignored by this width that is header/footer and some divs that contains only background colours to indicate certain area of the of the content page.

The modification should allow any other divs to ignore the body width not just the footer/header.

I cant use position absolute as I dont want to use that for my footer as it will mess up the footer positioning in the future.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}

.Frame {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}

.Row.Expand {
  height: auto;
}

.Row.footer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="Frame">


  <header class="Row">
    /*header should ignore body width*/
  </header>
  <section class="Row Expand">
    /*some div should ignore the body width*/
  </section>
  <footer class="Row footer">
    /*footer should ignore body width/*
    <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set a fixed width for the `<body>` tag. it's just trouble waiting to happen.

I think I understand the design you're going for. Here's a basic mock-up of what I would do:

```js
$('#main-content').css("min-height", $(window).height() - $("#footer").height() - $("#header").height() + "px");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

#header,
#footer,
#content-wapper,
section,
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section.image,
img {
  font-size: 0;
  display: block
}

#header,
#footer {
  background: #333;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

#main-content {
  background: #999;
}

.small {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2vw;
  background: #131418;
}

section p {
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.25
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="content-wrapper">

    <header id="header">
      /*header should ignore body width*/
    </header>

    <div id="main-content">
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1350/600" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1500/600" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/800/600" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/800/800" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1800/600" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea tale ubique legere, ex elit veri iudicabit eos. Vix at dicat pertinax, nibh libris nemore in mei, vis novum evertitur eu. Vim atqui ullum verterem ei, vocibus efficiantur te vim, elitr cetero adversarium an sit.
          Eu eam commune prodesset persequeris. Ex mel quod incorrupte. Cu choro congue dignissim usu. Vix no iisque patrioque, novum fierent singulis qui cu. Odio dolore altera mei ei, ex nam nonumy mollis. In vis invidunt senserit accommodare, vim persius
          aliquid instructior et. Ex quo appareat assentior, ornatus graecis minimum te usu.</p>
      </section>
    </div>


    <footer id="footer">
      /*footer should ignore body width/*
      <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>
```

You'll note that I added jQuery and a small script. That's what keeps the footer at the bottom of the page if the content is too short. Is that what you're trying to achieve with the footer?

it calculates the height of the header and the height of the footer and subtracts them from the height of the document then sets the min-height for #main-content to that value. The footer will always be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for :)  I will give it a shot

Comment: May I ask if there is a tutorial on this? did you get it from somewhere else? as I would like to read up on it :)

Comment: @Luke there is no tutorial for that particular example as I just wrote it as answer to your question. If you're interested you can read about Twitter's bootstrap framework as it uses a similar approach to the one I have here to organize content. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Ok no problem, thanks for spending the time writing the code :)

Comment: @luke No worries, I'm happy to help.

Comment: I been playing around with the code to understand it better. It seems that the jqurey is not working if the content is too short the footer will get shorter, i been trying to fix it, but im having bad time understanding it  :(

Comment: Never mind its working now. I didnt realised I had to put the jquery script at the bottom of the code lol

Comment: @luke glad you sorted it out. Again, just let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend if you only want to do it with header and footer? But either way the solution will resolve to this: remove the width on the body and add it to a `<div class="main-content"></div>` or as in the example below `<main class="main-content"></main>`.

```
    <body>
      <header></header>
      <main class="main-content">
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
      </main>
      <footer></footer>

</body>

.main-content {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Looking at your css there are so many question. Why do you set the `body` as `display: table;`?

Comment: To answer your question, i was following this article. https://pixelsvsbytes.com/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

Comment: Also its not just the header and footer that i want to ignore from the main div, there will also be divs inside the "main content" that I would like to ignore the main div width

Answer (score 0):

You could also attribute to header and footer a negative margin (from the moment we cross the 960px size with @media query).
I think width 100% will be maxed by 960px anyways so you have to ajust with too.

```
    @media (min-width: 960px) {
        footer, header {
            margin-left: calc( -(50vw-480px) );
            margin-right: calc( -(50vw-480px) );
            width: 100vw;
        }
    }
```

I do think it's the wrong way to approach the issue. But it does work (and have exceptionnal good applications).

Dejan.S's approach is way better : instead of limiting everything in width and try to undo this with some element -> limit only the elements that needs limitation.